# Insert from dynamic table input to mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a dynamic table form input form which you can add/remove rows as you like. As someone who doesn't have much experience, I'm stuck on how to save those input into the mySQL database.

Here's what the input.php looks like

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<div class="box-body no-padding">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="item" name="item"></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="no" name="no"disabled></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="qty" name="qty"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="price" name="price"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="total" name ="total" disabled></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="box-body">
  <div class="button-group">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-row"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Item</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box-footer">
  <div class="button-group pull-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And here is the JS (jQuery) code that I use to add/remove rows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".add-row").on('click', function(){
        var item = "<td><input type='text' id='item'></td>";
        var no = "<td><input type='text' id='no' disabled></td>";
        var qty = "<td><input type='number' id='qty'></td>";
        var price = "<td><input type='number' id='price'></td>";
        var total = "<td><input type='number' id='total' disabled></td>";
        var remove_button ="<td><button type='button' class='remove-row'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td>";

        var markup = "<tr>" + item + no + qty + price + total + remove_button + "</tr>";
        $("table").append(markup);
      });

      $(".table").on('click', '.remove-row', function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      });
    });
  });    
</script>
```

Here's what the page looks like:

[input page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE0WS.png)

insert.php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("db", $connection);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
  $item = $_POST['item'];
  $no = $_POST['no'];
  $qty = $_POST['qty'];
  $price = $_POST['price'];

  $query = mysql_query("insert into table(item, no, qty, price) values ('$item', '$no', '$qty', '$price')");
}

?>
```

I know the insert.php won't work for my case because I need to input it as arrays. The thing is:
1. I don't know how to implement the front end so I won't have duplicate id/names when I click "Add Item"
2. I don't know how to insert the arrays (that I don't know to create) to the mysql.

I'd like to know how can I implement the save button in my case. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, please research the mysql_* functions. They should no longer be used because they can lead to SQL injection security issues. Use mysqli_* instead or a DB layer like PDO.

Second, if you append "[]" to your input tag names then PHP will receive the data as arrays and you can loop through it in your insert.php.

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" id="item" name="item[]"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="no" name="no[]" disabled></td>
  <td><input type="number" id="qty" name="qty[]"></td>
  <td><input type="number" id="price" name="price[]"></td>
  <td><input type="number" id="total" name="total[]" disabled></td>
  <td><button type="button" class="remove-row"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

And be sure your javascript code also adds the name attribute:

```
$(".add-row").on('click', function(){
    var item = "<td><input type='text' id='item' name='item[]'></td>";
    var no = "<td><input type='text' id='no' name='no[]' disabled></td>";
    var qty = "<td><input type='number' id='qty' name='qty[]'></td>";
    var price = "<td><input type='number' id='price' name='price[]'></td>";
    var total = "<td><input type='number' id='total' name='total[]' disabled></td>";
    var remove_button ="<td><button type='button' class='remove-row'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button></td>";

    var markup = "<tr>" + item + no + qty + price + total + remove_button + "</tr>";
    $("table").append(markup);
  });
```

Then in PHP you can have:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $rowCount = count($_POST['item']);
    // Note that this assumes all the variables will correctly be submitted as arrays of the same length. For completeness and robustness you could add a !empty check for each value.
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {
        $item = $_POST['item'][$i];
        $no = $_POST['no'][$i];
        $qty = $_POST['qty'][$i];
        $price = $_POST['price'][$i];

        $query = mysqli_query($connection, "insert into `table` (item, no, qty, price) values ('$item', '$no', '$qty', '$price')");
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I got this error after clicking the submit button `Warning: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)` on the for line. Also this error message that says `Notice: Undefined offset: 1` on every variable in the for loop. And the loop keep going on forever until it reach fatal error after exceeding execution times.

Comment: I had an error in the for loop where "i" should have been "$i". I have updated the example.

Comment: This works for me now. Thanks
Also, for the table name as it's using reserved word in mysql, you have to escape it  by wrapping back tick " ` " around it.

Comment: You're right about the table name. Glad this helped.